# Generate a UNIQUE ID like Youtube's Playlist - PHP

Tags: php, youtube, unique, url-shortener

I have read [this tutorial](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_short_ids_with_php_like_youtube_or_tinyurl/) many times, finally, i finished to create my own unique id like Youtube.

But i can't find out how to create this kind of unique ID:

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL124C2FA58C814231

Some examples:
E5DBC5AD85E952BF
F26D47E15E785137
4DE9165CE24633D0
26B44580D7ECDCD3
--- with prefixes PL --
PL3F16C0AE0309BB56
PL124C2FA58C814231

How can i create that kind of unique id using PHP? My database used auto incremental PRIMARY KEY.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

PHP has a [`uniqid()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.uniqid.php) function for this purpose.  Pass the prefix to it as its first parameter:

```
$id = uniqid("PL");

// PL4e2b26588bec0
```

If this is needed for security purposes, there are better options discussed on the PHP document page.

Comment: I know this function but i want to create an ID which can be decode to number like this one http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_short_ids_with_php_like_youtube_or_tinyurl/  . Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why need it to decode to a number?  You just store it as a column in your database   which maps to the auto-incremented primary key.  These are all hex characters, so you can use `hexdec()` after stripping off the prefix to make a decimal number.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Michael! It's very useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo 'PL' . strtoupper(md5(time()));
```

Then obviously check your datasource to see if the value is unique.

Comment: This is very true, it's a quick and dirty solution, hence I suggested checking the value for uniqueness.

Comment: If we use md5, the string is too long and cannot be decode to number like this one http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_short_ids_with_php_like_youtube_or_tinyurl/  . Is there other way?

Comment: Yes - by using Kevin's script found at the link you provided.

Comment: I have tried many ways to tune the script, but it cannot generate a 16 chars id like this: E5DBC5AD85E952BF . That script got problems with it limit and from 11 chars.

Comment: Why does it matter that you have 16 chars?

Comment: I don't want to store 16 chars of unique ID in mysql, it's not a great idea. 16 chars is not important for me, but on side of researching, i wonder how can they create that kind of unique id for user's playlist. After a coupe of hours searching, i think E5DBC5AD85E952BF is a hex string. You know any solution for my stupid?